# suppress visual studio 2010 javascript parsing error on specific file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I have a javascript function of which its name is generated from the model in a ASP MVC razor view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function @(Model.GetWindowFunctionName)() {
        var win = $('#@(Model.WindowId)').data('tWindow');
        return win;
    }
</script>
```

Visual studio 2010 shows a number of compilation errors around the function name.

Is there a way to stop showing javascript errors for a specific file instead of disable all errors with Options/TextEditor/Javascript ?

Comment: Alternatively, you could find a way to code this that isn't invalid JavaScript.

Comment: The generated javascript is correct and works fine.

Comment: I know that. But as JavaScript, the "@(Model)" stuff is invalid. Also, I personally _hate_ generating JavaScript. I like to run the same code on every page.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, I'd restructure your code to be valid JavaScript. Rather than re-work your whole system, you can take advantage of the fact that you can use strings as property names on JavaScript objects, and the fact that `window` is the global object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window['@(Model.GetWindowFunctionName)'] = function() {
    var win = $('#@#(Model.WindowId)').data('tWindow');
    return win;
};

</script>
```

That would be valid JavaScript, and is functionally the same as the sample you provided.